# How to sum a single value to a single dictionary item?

Tags: python, dictionary

Seems extremely easy, although I haven´t find the answer easily.

Take this dict:

`my_dict = {'my_key':1.5}`

Take this float:

`f = 0.5`

How can I add this float value to a single dictionary item?

This is my wrong code, but you get the idea:

`my_dict['my_key'][0] = my_dict['my_key'][0] + f`

Comment: `my_dict['my_key'] += f` ?

Comment: `my_dict` is a dictionary, and `my_dict['my_key']` is a float, so you shouldn't be accessing the float with `my_dict['my_key'][0]`, `my_dict['my_key']` will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access dictionary items by supplying the item key so in this case just type:

```
my_dict['my_key'] = my_dict['my_key'] + f
```

and you're golden refer [Here](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/) for more on how to use dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

I think it was just syntax on a) accessing the value for that key, b) using it as a float and c) updating the original key's value?

```
my_dict = {'my_key':1.5}

f= 0.5

my_dict['my_key'] = float(my_dict['my_key'])+ f

print(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

the code will be:

ans= my_dict['my_key'] + f

print(ans)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the update method of dictionaries:

```py
>>> my_dict = {'my_key':1.5}
>>> f = 0.5

>>> new_value = my_dict['my_key'] + f

>>> my_dict.update({'my_key': new_value})
```